# How can I get an interface{} argument to point to something else?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

How can I make the following work and make the output `"Result is: [Value from GetFromMemory]."`?

Unfortunately I cannot change the method signatures of `GetItem` and `Get`.

http://play.golang.org/p/R5me3Q3y4W

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Key string

type Item struct {
    Key   Key
    Value string
}

func GetItem(key Key) interface{} {
    return &Item{key, "Value from GetFromMemory"}
}

// How can I make item point to the one created in GetItem?
func Get(key Key, item interface{}) {
    item = GetItem(key)
}

func main() {
    var item Item
    Get("Key1", &item)

    // This should print "Result is: [Value from GetFromMemory]."
    fmt.Printf("Result is: [%s].", item.Value)
}
```

Comment: Maybe GetItem should return a *Item? Maybe Get should return an interface{} rather than update a variable passed in?

Comment: @Anonymous OP explicitly stated that he can't change the signatures of both functions. This is probably because they're part of the [GAE datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Get).

Comment: This is exactly right @nemo. I am trying to marry the [GAE Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Get) with the [Gorilla Context API](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context#Get) in order to check memory for a struct before going to the datastore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you're dealing with `interface{}` values you either need [type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or reflection.

If you know which types you will deal with, type assertions are probably the way to go
([Code on play](http://play.golang.org/p/PT8YsuhAkZ)):

```
func GetItem(key Key) interface{} {
    return &Item{key, "Value from GetFromMemory"}
}

func Get(key Key, item interface{}) {
    switch v := item.(type) {
        case **Item:
            *v = GetItem(key).(*Item)
    }
}

// Usage:
var item *Item
Get("Key1", &item)
```

The code in `Get` is laid out so that you can easily add more conditions for several more 
types. The [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) checks the underlying type of `item`. In this case it is a
pointer to a pointer to an `Item` (it was `*Item` in main, then we gave `Get` the address of `&item`, making it a `**Item`).

In the section that matches when the type matches, we can then call `GetItem`, assert that the resulted object is of type `*Item` and copy it to `*v`.

Note that I changed the `item` variable to `*Item` as you're producing a pointer value in `GetItem`, so it makes more sense to get the pointer instead of a copy of an `Item` object.

Also note that you **need to check the result of type assertions** like the one used to 
retrieve the value from `GetItem`. If you don't and the type does not match, say, `*Item`,
your code will blow up with a runtime panic.

Checked type assertions:

```
v, ok := someInterfaceValue.(SomeType)
// ok will be true if the assertion succeeded
```

For the sake of completeness, you can solve your problem with reflection as well.
Define `Get` as follows ([Example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/iQHk-oibNx)):

```
func Get(key Key, item interface{}) {
    itemp := reflect.ValueOf(item).Elem()
    itemp.Set(reflect.ValueOf(GetItem(key)))
}
```

What happens is that at first the reflected value of `item` (type `**Item`) is dereferenced,
assuming that it is a pointer value, giving us a reflected value with type `*Item`. Said
value is then set with the reflected value of `GetItem` by using the `Set` method.

Of course you will need to check whether the kind of `item` is actually a pointer. 
Not doing this and passing a non-pointer value to `Get` will result in panics.

Comment: Thanks @nemo! This is exactly what I was looking for and I learnt a lot from your comprehensive answer so thanks! In fact I took the liberty of producing the examples without the extra indirection of the double pointers for others to use. See http://play.golang.org/p/cRqqgkjuFX for the ```switch``` code and http://play.golang.org/p/ubiq_7uev2 for the reflection code.